# Spark - How to calculate percentiles in Spark 1.6 dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark 1.6. I need to find multiple percentiles for a column in dataframe. My data is huge with atleast 10 million records. I tried using hive context like below

```
hivecontext.sql("select percentile_approx(col,0.25),percentile_approx(col,0.5) from table")
```

But this approach is very slow and takes a lot of time. I heard about approxQuantile but seems it is available in spark 2.x. Is there any alternate approach in spark 1.6 using spark dataframe to improve performance.

I saw another approach using hive UDAF like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{callUDF, lit}

df.agg(callUDF("percentile_approx", $"someColumn", lit(0.8)).as("percentile80"))
```

Will the above approach improve performance.

Comment: The only way I can see doing this is through something like this (this will take a lot of local memory though). (1) persist the DF locally, (2) sort on your field with a window to create a row_id, (3) find the 80% point and do a where, (4) turn the cell to an array via `val 80Percentile = inputDF.selectExpr(columnName).rdd.map(x=>x.mkString.toLong).collect` , and (5) `inputDF.withColumn("80th_percentile", lit(80Percentile(0)))`. The only other way I can see this going quickly is if you sample your data by 10% so it has less to run on, and pray your data is, relatively, normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used percentile_approx(col,array(percentile_value_list)) function. Then split returned array to individual . It improved performance without calling function multiple times.